# $conn->prepare keeps returning false

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

$conn is a database connect that I have used previously to get information so it works. prepare is returning false and I don't know why.

```
$updateWeight = "insert into $username (weight, date) values (?,?)";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($updateWeight))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("is",$weight,$date);
    $stmt->execute();
    die("Added ". $weight . " " . $date);
}
else
{
    die( "$updateWeight with $weight and $date error 1");
}
```

This returns "insert into testing (weight, date) values (?,?) with 150 and 2015/06/16 error 1".

Here is the table as far as I can tell everything is fine

```
mysql> select * from testing;
+----+--------+------------+
| id | weight | date       |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |    200 | 2015/06/10 |
+----+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I'm sure the error is something minor and stupid but I can't seem to find it.

I copy and pasted the command into mysql and it worked after replacing the variables

```
mysql> insert into testing (weight, date) values (150,"2015/06/15"); 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by putting $conn->close(); and then recreating $conn as I had used it previously

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

Your query uses a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) - `DATE`. What you can do to bypass this is to use a backtick (`).

```
$updateWeight = "INSERT INTO `$username` (`weight`, `date`) VALUES (?,?)";
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, to determine the error why it returns false, lets do [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Put this inside your `else()` condition:

```
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
```

Comment: That gives     insert into testing (`weight`, `date`) values (?,?) with 150 and 2015/06/16 error 1    I'm not sure how to escape them on here but the backtics are there

Comment: What is your `$username`, and your `$conn`? Did you establish your `$conn` before your given code?

Comment: Yes I use the same $conn in a select before this so I know it works and the $username is testing which is repeated when the else prints the statement

Comment: @dlrdlrdlr - updated my answer. Put an error reporting inside your `else()`, and let us see the error why it returns false.

Comment: I tried with and without backtics and I get this both times `Errormessage:  
insert into testing (`weight`, `date`) values (?,?) with 150 and 2015/06/16 error 1`    The error message is on its own line and blank. The new code is `            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
            die( "<br>$updateWeight with $weight and $date error 1");
`

Comment: @dlrdlrdlr - Remove both `die()` and try it again. And is this query inside another query? If it is, add `$stmt->close();` after you execute your query. It is important to close your statement after using it so it won't affect other queries as well, especially if you're going to use `$stmt` variable again.

Comment: Ok Still getting `Errormessage: ` and I don't know what a query inside a query is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80627/discussion-between-logan-wayne-and-dlrdlrdlr).